# Зависает выполнение скрипта ExecuteAsyncScript в IJavaScriptExecutor

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

На веб странице удается начать кнопку только используя `IJavaScriptExecutor`.
Кнопка нажимается и все отлично но код дальше не выполняется. И потом `WebDriverTimeoutException : script timeout`.

Почему залипает код, и что с ним можно сделать? На локатор сильно не обращайте внимание.

```cs
public void JSexecutor()
{
    var elem = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='button-play button2 button2_rounded button2_w-icon local-icon-theme-white page-artist__play button-play__type_artist']"));
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
    js.ExecuteAsyncScript("arguments[0].click();",elem); //Происходит нажатие и код виснет      
}
```

Пробовал сделать повторный клик на этот же элемент путем дублирования кода но тоже не привело к успеху.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно у вас работает так, как и должно.

Для того, чтобы понять, почему оно записает, надо уловить разницу между `ExecuteScript` и `ExecuteAsyncScript`.

Первый просто выполняет скрипт.

```cs
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);
```

Сделайте так, и проблема решена.

`ExecuteAsyncScript` предназначен для выполнения асинхронных скриптов, то есть тех, которые завершаются раньше, чем будут получены необходимые данные, например AJAX запрос. Самый простой пример, это вызов с задержкой.

```cs
object response = js.ExecuteAsyncScript(
    "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" + // колбэк передается как последний аргумент
    "setTimeout(() => { arguments[0].click(); callback('success'); }, 5000);"
    , elem);
Debug.WriteLine(response);
```

Очевидно, что такой скрипт вы не сможете выполнить и получить строчку `success` с помощью простого `ExecuteScript`.

Так же для случаев, когда коллбэк может быть не вызван в отведенное время для избежания зависаний, как у вас в вопросе, можно выставить таймаут выполнения скриптов.

```cs
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```